# Browser requires some files twice

Tags: html, webserver, esp32

I wrote a very simple web page on an ESP32:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <script src="js/dayjs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/submit" method="post">
        <label for="actual-datetime">Set datetime</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" id="actual-datetime" name="actual-datetime" value="" step="1"><br>
    
        <label for="rtc">RTC datetime</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" id="rtc" name="rtc" value="" step="1">
    
        <hr>

        <label for="alarm1">Alarm clock 1</label>
        <input type="time" id="alarm1" name="alarm1" value="">
        <select name="action1" id="action1">
            <option value="wakeup">Wakeup</option>
            <option value="standby">Standby</option>
            <option value="idle">Idle</option>
        </select><br>

        <label for="alarm2">Alarm clock 2</label>
        <input type="time" id="alarm2" name="alarm2" value="">
        <select name="action2" id="action2">
            <option value="wakeup">Wakeup</option>
            <option value="standby">Standby</option>
            <option value="idle">Idle</option>
        </select><br>

        <label for="alarm3">Alarm clock 3</label>
        <input type="time" id="alarm3" name="alarm3" value="">
        <select name="action3" id="action3">
            <option value="wakeup">Wakeup</option>
            <option value="standby">Standby</option>
            <option value="idle">Idle</option>
        </select><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open this page from my browser (Firefox 101) I notice that some files are requested twice:

[image]

Is there a reason for that?
How to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Did you empty your network view since the last page load? It might be recording all requests

Comment: @Andy, yes I did.